# What does this line of Visual Basic code in a Microsoft Access program mean?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm debugging a program made by a former coworker in Microsoft Access. The program suddenly stopped working today and this line of code appears to be causing the crash. (The error code that appears is 3646, aka data type mismatch). I have no experience in VB and SQL so I am unsure what it means.

```
NewIndexNumber = Nz(DMax("Mid$([IndexNumbers],5,3)", "QYearOtherRecordList2"), "000")
```

In particular, I am unsure what "Mid$([IndexNumbers],5,3)" is supposed to do. I don't know what the dollar sign means. The index numbers, by the way, are just strings of numbers like "018374".

Comment: While the existing answers already address your obvious question, there seems to be an underlying question (or problem, at least) in "this line of code appears to be causing the crash". Do you get any error message/number that you can tell us? Or did you leave out that part on purpose? (Either to ask in a separate question or to figure it out yourself?)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the error code. It's 3464, i.e., data type mismatch.

Comment: The only thing I can think of in this case is that the values in the field `IndexNumbers` might not be strings, as the `Mid$()` function is accepting only strings. Not sure if there is the possibility of implicit type conversion in this case (it definitely happens if you do `Debug.Print Mid$(234, 2 , 1)`, but whether it happens in this inner function call, I don't know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other 2 answers state, the `$` on the `Mid` function forces it to expect a string input parameter and return a string value.  And the effective meaning of that portion of the command `Mid$([IndexNumbers],5,3)` is that it will return characters 5 through 7 of the `IndexNumbers` column.

**However, the full meaning of that line of code (which is the title of your question) is the following:**

According to that line of code, you have a query or table in your database (presumably a query) named `QYearOtherRecordList2`.  That code is issuing a [DMax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.dmax) function call against that query, which will return the "Maximum String Value" of characters 5 through 7 of the `IndexNumbers` column for that query (Using the [Mid$](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function) function).

```
'Example output sample
'Lets assume that the query, with the Mid$ function applied returns the following rows

001
034
555
142
099

'Then, the DMax function would return just the following as the Max of those values

555
```

Finally, to insure that `NewIndexNumber` contains a usable value, the `DMax` is wrapped in an [Nz](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.nz) function call that means that if for some reason `DMax` returns a `Null` value (i.e. there are no records return from your query, or none of the existing `IndexNumbers` values are greater than 4 characters) then we return the value "000" so that `NewIndexNumber` will contain something useful.

Based on some quick testing that I performed to try and duplicate your error, I would suspect that maybe the `QYearOtherRecordList2` query has possibly changed (or maybe there is other code prior to this statement that affects the results of `QYearOtherRecordList2`) that is the true cause of your error `3464 - Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

BTW - In your comments, you mentioned the correct error number for that message, and in your updated post, you typo'd the number.  But in both cases, you truncated the error message, which is something you should not do when asking for help.  That last part of the message `in criteria expression` is actually **VITALLY** important to understanding where the issue may lie and in how to debug this problem.

That part of the message is what points to the possibility that the error is actually in a `criteria` also known as a `where` clause or condition.  This is why I believe the issue is indirectly related to the line of code where the error occurs.  There is nothing fundamentally wrong with that line of code, but that line of code does rely on the `QYearOtherRecordList2` query successfully returning a dataset without an error.

So, please, please, in the future, accurately include the error number and FULL error message text to help us help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`Mid$(Something, 5, 3)` returns 3 characters from string *Something*, starting at position 5.

E.g. `?Mid$("1234567890", 5, 3)` returns `567`.

This code seems to take characters 5 till 7 from the previous index number, and if that's `Null`, return three zeroes instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to the `Mid()` function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/mid-function

The `Mid$()` function always returns a string and only works on strings, while `Mid()` also works on Variants.